# Docker Run With SELinux on ubuntu Constrain violation

Tags: ubuntu, docker, lxc, selinux

On Ubuntu 14.04, I run Docker with SELinux，As I Known,Docker will Read $Selinux-Root-Dir/default/contexts/lxc_contexts。but I can't find this file,so I create this file and puts some contents.following:

```
process = "system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0"
content = "system_u:object_r:virt_var_lib_t:s0"
file = "system_u:object_r:svirt_lxc_file_t:s0"
sandbox_kvm_process = "system_u:system_r:svirt_qemu_net_t:s0"
sandbox_lxc_process = "system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0"
```

then I Run Docker with Selinux's Permissive Mode,
`docker -dD --selinux-enabled=false`
and `docker run -it --rm ubuntu /bin/bash`

At last I want to use audit2allow to generate a *.te and *.pp file,
I execute `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M container`,but it said 

`compilation failed:
container.te:41:ERROR 'syntax error' at token 'mlsconstrain' on line 41:
   #Constraint rule: 
    mlsconstrain chr_file { create relabelto } ((h1 dom h2 -Fail-)  and (l2 eq h2) ); Constraint DENIED
/usr/bin/checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
/usr/bin/checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from container.te`

I cat the container.te,its contents is:

 `#!!!! This avc is a constraint violation.  You would need to modify the attributes of either the source or target types to allow this access.
 #Constraint rule: 
    mlsconstrain chr_file { create relabelto } ((h1 dom h2 -Fail-)  and (l2 eq h2) ); Constraint DENIED
mlsconstrain chr_file { relabelfrom } ((h1 dom h2 -Fail-) ); Constraint DENIED
....
  # Possible cause is the source level (s0) and target level (s0:c96,c879) are different.`

I guess the docker run with s0,but it want to relabel the docker's rootfs file system to (s0:c96,c879) and this error happen.

So My Question:

Is the Type for the container error?how to close this constrains or how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know line 41 of your container.te file. In general 'syntax error' indicates a missing selinux-type or an unknown selinux-interface, which means that the problem is at a different place.

But there are some things that I noticed:

- The Docker Daemon have to run with`--selinux-enabled=true` to support SELinux
- To create a new selinux policy module you need all these files: .te, .fc and .if. See the [Debian how-to](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.selinux.html) for an example of a minimal SELinux policy.
- By using `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M container` you work on all logged linies. Better you copy only needed lines into a new file.
- `s0` is the level not a label. While 'relabeling' means to change the type. See [labeling files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html).
- At runtime SELinux (not docker itself) will relabel the docker daemon type (docker_t) and running containers (svirt_lxc_net_t).
- Docker change the category of file by default (i.e. s0:c96,c879) to separate running containers from each other.

By default Ubuntu is preinstalled with AppArmor, you have remove/disable it first if you want to work with SELinux. Ubuntu and Debian do not ship a Docker policy for SELinux.

Possible solutions:

- Use AppArmor with Ubuntu (but i don't known if there is a ready-to-use Docker profile).
- Build your own Docker policy for SELinux on Ubuntu. See [Fedora-Cloud Docker SELinux](https://github.com/fedora-cloud/docker-selinux) policy, but there are a lot of dependencies, i.e. `svirt_lxc_net_t` is from [virt.te](https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy/blob/f22-contrib/virt.te)
- Use Fedora, which will work with SELinux and Docker out-of-the-box, including the mentioned file `lxc_contexts`.